# Undefined var while adding data in Object

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-declaration

I need to create a 2-level hierarchy in the object temp. And i write the following :

```
var temp = {};
temp['mailboxes'].push("First");
```

The following code gives me an error stating that `no method push of undefined` and this is understandable since I know that when using arrays / objects they need to be declared first. Is there any direct way to do this so that I will not have to declare the same before having to use the var?

For example, I will want to avoid doing :

```
var temp = {}; 
temp['mailboxes'] = [];
```

Comment: How would JS engine know you want an array if you don't state that?

Answer (score 2):

`var temp = { mailboxes: [] }`

as far as i know javascript has no easy way of giving default values like python's `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it is by declaring the mailboxes array in the object like:

```
var temp = {mailboxes: []};
```

This way when you push the value in your array.. the JS Engine will know where to push the value. You can't do it without declaring it  first. What you want to do is pushing values in an empty object's undefined field, which will ofcourse give error.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help

```
var temp = {};
temp.mail = new Array();

temp.mail.push("email");
temp.mail.push("email");
```

you need to initialize first the object property before you can
manipulate contents;